# RapidSSL not trusted using the check on "why no padlock"

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https

On http://www.whynopadlock.com/check.php  whilst testing the following url https://www.bobclubs.com/pay I get the following message:-

ERROR: cannot verify www.bobclubs.com's certificate, issued by `/C=US/O=GeoTrust, Inc./CN=RapidSSL CA': Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.

I am not 100 sure why this is as all issuer is OK, all items are secure and I get a padlock on all browsers.

[image: No pad lock message]

Can any one shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most probably you did not install intermediate certificate included in message you've received from rapid ssl. take a look [here](https://knowledge.geotrust.com/support/knowledge-base/index?page=content&id=AR1422).

Comment: Since the site works in a browser, that's evidently not the problem.

Comment: not necessarily. i use rapidssl as well and saw validating tools failing and browsers not warning.

Comment: @pQd A good example is mobile devices which don't update their cert storage as Android <2.2 did when Geotrust and RapidSSL changed their root cert.

Comment: Firefox has the CA certs for both RapidSSL and GeoTrust CA. That means that the chain will work all the way back to GeoTrust even if the server doesn't present the GeoTrust cert. If you remove the RapidSSL cert from the browser's list of CA certs, the browser will give you a warning. You can test this easily with openssl verify, too.

Comment: @jenny D - can you please tell then what's the point of intermediate cert? thx!

Comment: I misspoke - it's the GeoTrust that doesn't need to be checked if the browser trusts RapidSSL, not the other way around. The point of the intermediate cert is to have a chain of certificates to follow from the client certificate base back to the trusted certificate authority. If the browser trusts the intermediate certificate as a valid CA, then you don't need the base CA as well.

Comment: @Jenny D - thanks a lot for your answer. can you please take a look here: http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://www.bobclubs.com/pay - i still think it's missing intermediate cert.

Comment: Both certificates are there, and if I store them in my CACert dir and run openssl verify on them, it works. It may be that they are presented in the wrong order; Java is sensitive to that while most browsers aren't. (And yes, I've found that out the hard way.) The fix for that is simply to move the certificates around in the cacert file.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I needed to go here https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=AR1548&actp=RELATED_RESOURCE and install primary/secondary certs

Answer (score 5):

Presumably, whatever list of trusted CA certificates that `whynopadlock.com` uses does not include the CA certificate at the root of the trust chain used by your certificate.  Given that you claim that browsers seem to trust the certificate, then I'd say it's a limitation of the testing site.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you did not setup the intermediate certificate correctly.
Most browsers will still show the lock in this situation.

Take a look at this verifier from rapidssl:
https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO9556

And fix by following this document (Apache):
https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO6252&actp=LIST&viewlocale=en_US

Or this one (IIS):
https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO10517&actp=LIST&viewlocale=en_US